# Sklearn matplotlib coloring clusters by unique values in figure and showing labels that correspond to these cluster colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, pca

I want to get set up a label/legend that will correspond to the colors of my clusters after running a PCA. Ex. Here the clusters are colored by a value 1-4.

**See Attached Image

1) I want it to have a legend that shows which group of values correspond to which 1-4 value. I tried np.unique() and that did not work.

2) Also, for coloring the clusters by lets say BMI, how can I set this as a range to group them by and still show a legend of those color ranges?

```
data = pd.read_table('test.txt', header=None)
data.columns =  ['age', 'score', 'ASA', 'BMI']

from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
#_ = pd.scatter_matrix( data, figsize=(30,30))

pca = PCA(n_components=data.shape[1])
pca.fit(data)


data_pca = pca.transform(data)


fig = plt.figure( figsize=(24,8))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(131)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(132)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(133)
ax1.scatter( data_pca[:,0], data_pca[:,1], alpha=0.5, s=25, c=data.ASA)
ax2.scatter( data_pca[:,2], data_pca[:,1], alpha=0.5, s=25, c=data.ASA)
ax3.scatter( data_pca[:,2], data_pca[:,3], alpha=0.5, s=25, c=data.ASA,label=np.unique(data.ASA))
plt.legend(loc = 'right')
plt.show()
```

[PCA with sklearn / matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksSXE.png)